# MYSQL-Script to query 2 tables and get matches on house number and postcode

Tags: mysql

Bit of a mysql noob here im going to need a script that I will run with cron jobs once a night to compare 2 tables and look for matches based on the "House_number" and "postcode" columns
The matches will be identified and then a text file will generated.
Ideally i would like to get this emailed to me via sendmail or equivelant.

The two tables are named
user_table
business_table

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried and what you have so far. Also a table schema will help.

Comment: Hi Ryan , I havent set this up yet but im going to. I just need some initial help.I will have 2 tables with columns "postcode" and "house_number" I will need a script to compare them looking for matches based these 2 columns

Comment: When you say compare, what do you mean. A house number can be 42 and a post code can be 7800

Comment: basically i need to know what exactly you are trying to achieve. because comparing two tables can be done via a join or two queries.

Comment: Hi Ryan and thanks for you patience, yes lets say on user_table and business_table we have an entries where the "house_number" is 42 and the poscode is 7800. But i also have another 2 entries that are matches says "house_number"=43 and postcode=7801. I would need it to weed out all the matches and output to a txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are a noob and need quite some help i put this together for you, please note this has not been tested and its very crude when it comes to optimizing and re usability but something like this, it will be up to you to test :)

```
<?php 
    //store this in a seperate file or leave it here
    $databaseDetails = array(
        'host' => 'localhost', 
        'dbName' => 'databaseName',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password'
    );

    //instantiate our final array
    $houseArr = array();

    try {

        //connection using PDO (very secure)
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$databaseDetails['host'].';dbname='.$databaseDetails['dbname'], $databaseDetails['username'], $databaseDetails['password']);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        //This commented out section is to show you how to prepare a query
        /*
        $prepare = $conn->prepare('SELECT house_number, post_code FROM user_table WHERE created = :date');
        $prepare->execute(array(
            'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('Now'))
        ));
        */

        //query for users
        $data = $conn->query('SELECT id, house_number, post_code /*Additional fields here*/ FROM user_table');

        //this will create an array of data that i will explain below
        foreach($data as $row) {
            $houseArr[$row['house_number']]['users'][$row['id']] = $row['post_code'];   
        }

        //query for business
        $data = $conn->query('SELECT id, house_number, post_code /*Additional fields here*/ FROM business_table');

        //this will create an array of data that i will explain below
        foreach($data as $row) {
            $houseArr[$row['house_number']]['business'][$row['id']] = $row['post_code'];    
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }

    if(!empty($houseArr)) {

        /*
         *  the houseArr will have house_number as an index, then it will have multiple entries under either users or business
         * for example 
         * user house 43 and postcode 7800 with database id 1900
         * user house 43 and postcode 7801 with database id 1950
         * business house 43 and postcode 7800 with database id 2000
         * business house 43 and postcode 7801 with database id 2050
         * user house 42 and postcode 5400 with database id 2100
         * business house 42 and postcode 7600 with database id 2200
         *   
         * the array will spit out 
         * array(
         *      43 =>                       This is where the house number will be
         *          'user' =>               This is where all the users with house number x will be
         *              '1900' => '7800',   This is a key pair value of the id of the user and the post code they entered
         *              '1910' => '7801'
         *          'business' =>           This is where all the businesses will be with house number x 
         *              '2000' => '7800',   This is a key pair value of the id of the business and the post code they entered
         *              '2050' => '7801'
         *      42 => 
         *          'user' => 
         *              '2100' => 5400,
         *          'business' => 
         *              '2200' => 7600
         * )
         * 
         */

        //this will write the txt file
        file_put_contents('address.txt', print_r($houseArr, true)); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ryan thanks a million for this. Ill test this and should hopefully get this to work. You are a star thanks

Comment: No problem, any time :)